# cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD while trying to update theos

Tags: ios, git, theos, tweak

I cannot seem to run make update-theos

it throws me

```
> Updating Theos…
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
make: *** [update-theos] Error 1
```

Here's what I got doing ls -l

[image]

Comment: And are permissions correct?

Comment: Yes. I've also made sure I've chmod 755 {foldername}

Comment: what about user:group?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak how would I check permissions?

Comment: not sure about macos but in linux: `ls -l`

Comment: @MichałWalenciak https://imgur.com/a/OB7ks here's my permission folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165096/discussion-between-dilli-and-michal-walenciak).